# Comparar dos DataFrame y modificar un campo que no sea NaN

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

Tengo dos `DataFrame` y necesito llenar los `NaN` con los valores que se encuentran en el `df1`, en el campo `tipo` (que no sea `NaN`)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','33','44','11','22'],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse','monitor','usb',np.nan,np.nan]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','33','44'],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse',np.nan,np.nan]
                    })
```

Necesito guardar en el `df2`, los valores que estan en `NaN`, con el nombre del `tipo`,
en el ejemplo uso dos `DataFrame` con dimensiones pequeñas, pero llevandolo a millones de registros, hay alguna forma
 'mágica' de los `pandas` y/o `numpy` que pueden solucionar este problema, llevandolo a un tiempo de ejecución menor que de la forma en la que lo planteo?

```
df2['tipo'] = [df1[df1['id'] == row['id']]['tipo'].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)[0] for index,row in df2.iterrows()]
```

Comment: ¿Quieres conservar las filas con los valores NaN que no tengan un valor en df1?

Comment: Si, seria lo ideal

Comment: el df1 es producto de un `cross join`, en el ejemplo lo puse con dos campos, pero la realidad es que trae mas campos

Comment: Las columnas que tengas no es problema,  me refiero a que hay id duplicadas en tu ejemplo, si esto pasa en tu dataframe real, imagina que tienes `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','11'],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse', 'np.nan']`
                   })  la id 11 está asociada a "teclado" y a nan, si tenemos un 11 con Nan en df2 lo substituimos por teclado o lo dejamos como nan? Es más y si se diera esta situación  `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','11'],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse', 'usb']
                   })` ?

Comment: No es algo trivial incluso en la primera situación, si no hay ids duplicadas en la primera columna lo que quieres hacer es trivial usándola como índice, sin hay id duplicadas la cosa se complica

Comment: la situación de "duplicado" solo se da con np.nan , por eso en el ejemplo cuando hago el filtro, le aplico dropna() y tomo el primer resultado, (o sea 'teclado') en tu consulta

Comment: Vale he pasado por alto lo de dropna... eso simplifica las cosas y mucho. Dado que mencionas tener más campos/columnas en tu caso real ¿Las otras columnas también deberían rellenarse o solo la columna tipo?

Comment: solo la columna tipo, gracias por tu comprensión

Comment: `pd.merge(df2,df1,on='id').drop(['tipo_x'],axis=1).dropna()` hice algo asi

Comment: Lucas esa es una buena solución, solo que si tienes ids con NaN en df2 que no están en df1 las elimina, esa era la razón de mi primer comentario precisamente. Si esto no te importa merge es una posibilidad, puedes publicarlo como respuesta si quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posibilidad es hacer que `id` sea el índice del DataFramene y usar `fillna`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','33','44','11','22'],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse','monitor','usb',np.nan,np.nan]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['11','22','33', "44", "55", "33"],
                    'tipo':['teclado','mouse',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan]
                    })

aux = df1.loc[~df1.tipo.isna(), ("id", "tipo")].set_index("id").tipo
df2.set_index("id", inplace=True)
df2.tipo.fillna(aux, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df2
>
>
>        tipo
> id         
> 11  teclado
> 22    mouse
> 33  monitor
> 44      usb
> 55      NaN
> 33  monitor
> ```

`pandas.Series.fillna` puede recibir como argumento otra serie de la que tomará los valores a usar para substituir los NaN. Básicamente busca un valor NaN, toma el índice asociado al mismo y busca dicho indice en la segunda serie. Si lo encuentra usa el valor asociado para substituir el NaN de la primera, si no lo encuentra deja el NaN.

En nuestro caso, `aux` es la serie de la que se toman los valores a intercambiar por NaN, es algo así:

> ```
> id
> 11    teclado
> 22      mouse
> 33    monitor
> 44        usb
> Name: tipo, dtype: object
> ```

Cuando `df2.tipo.fillna` se encuentra el `id` `55` en `df2` lo busca en `aux`, como no lo encuentra en ella (no está en `df1`) lo deja como NAN en `df2`. En cambio `33` y `44` si son substituidos.

Si lo deseas puedes resetear el índice después y hacer que `id` sea de nuevo una columna más.

Comment: En el problema real, pasado a datos gigantes, mi clave es concatenada,y me arrojaba este error : *Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index*  Esto es el resultado de que.. como en el df1 figura varias veces la clave, como comentaba, el df1 viene de un `cross join` y `left join`, entonces antes de hacer fillna(), hago esto `aux = aux[~aux.index.duplicated()]`.  Es correcto lo que digo ?, porque al parecer lo toma bien

Comment: Si es correcto, incluso lo puedes hacer al  crear `aux` directamente, con lo que ahorras memoria al ser `aux` mas pequeño al carecer de duplicados de inicio : `aux = df1.loc[~df1.tipo.isna() & ~df1.tipo.duplicated(), ("id", "tipo")].set_index("id").tipo`